# How to find point position relation between two images using homography?

Tags: opencv, matrix, computer-vision, homography

I'm working on vision project with OPENCV :  how to find point x position in an image B
knowing it's position in image A?

and that the two projections are of the same plane ( the floor).
thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

Assume that you have a Point A with homogeneous coordinate :

`A = [x, y, 1]`

Maybe you also have an homography H like this:

    `H = [h00 h01 h02;
         h10 h11 h12;
         h20 h21 h22]`

Then do the product H * A' where A' is the transpose of A

You will get something like this

   `Bs = [X, Y, s]`

You have to normalize the result by s in order to have

    `B = [Xb, Yb, 1]`